# Spring Web Flow & Java Server Faces @ManagedProperty injection always null during flow

Tags: java, spring, jsf, spring-webflow, managed-property

I have succesfully integrated JSF with Spring WebFlow & PrimeFaces, **but injection by @ManagedProperty is always NULL** during my web flow but using @Autowired annotation injection works. **I would like to know why @ManagedProperty does not work but @Autowired works.**

My enviroment: Spring 3.2.1.RELEASE, JSF 2.2.4, PrimeFaces 3.0.

**UserBean class:**

```
     @ManagedBean
     public class UserBean implements Serializable {

         @ManagedProperty(value="#{messageBean}")
         private MessageBean messageBean;

         public MessageBean getMessageBean() {
           return messageBean;
         }

         public void setMessageBean(MessageBean messageBean) {
           this.messageBean = messageBean;
         }
     }
```

**MessageBean class:**

```
    @ManagedBean(name = "messageBean")
    public class MessageBean implements Serializable {
       public String getMessage(){
          return "Hello, " + name;
       }
    }
```

**faces-config.xml:**

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
```

**webflow.xml:**

```
<!-- Executes flows: the central entry point into the Spring Web Flow system -->
<flow-executor id="flowExecutor">
    <flow-execution-listeners>
        <listener ref="facesContextListener"/>
    </flow-execution-listeners>
</flow-executor>

<!-- The registry of executable flow definitions -->
<flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows">
    <flow-location-pattern value="/**/flow.xml" />
    <flow-location id="parent-flow" path="parent-flow.xml"/>
</flow-registry>

<!-- Configures the Spring Web Flow JSF integration -->
<faces:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices" development="true" />

<!-- A listener to create and release a FacesContext -->
<beans:bean id="facesContextListener" class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener"/>
```

I have also file flow.xml and view.xhtml because I have integrated spring web flow with JSF using PrimeFaces.

WEB-INF/flows/ajax-jsf/flow.xml:

```
<var name="userBean"    class="org.springframework.samples.webflow.ajax.UserBean" />
<var name="messageBean" class="org.springframework.samples.webflow.ajax.jsf.MessageBean" />

<view-state id="view">
    <transition on="suggest" >
        <evaluate expression="userBean.createEmailSuggestion(flowRequestContext)"
            result="viewScope.emailSuggestion" />
    </transition>
</view-state>
```

Do you know why my @ManagedProperty injection fails? If I replace @ManagedProperty with @Autowired I can see that object is created but @ManagedProperty is always null.

Comment: I only see jsf managed beans here, notthing spring related

Comment: Try to download this example: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-webflow-samples/tree/master/primefaces-showcase and than inject something using @ManagedProperty. Is always null... I really don't know why...

Comment: Sorry, that is too much work

Comment: ok, but i think it is a very strange mistake and it is a good opportunity to learn something new...

Comment: Learning something new for **me**? Well, I consider using Spring a step backwards, as is using JSF Managed Beans. I'm using CDI for a couple of years now...

Comment: I have updated my post, maybe it will be more clear to understand my problem :)